# Django Issues with Uploading a Python File

Tags: python, django, python-3.3

My code so far:

```
from django.core.files import File

file = open('ChicagoTimesScores.py')
djangofile = File(file)
myfile = File(file)
myfile.save('new', djangofile)
file.close()
```

I'm aware of repeating myfile, but I was a bit lost and tried what I could to see if it work.

My error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/TestRun.py", line 6, in <module>
    myfile.save('new', djangofile)
AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'save'
```

I'm trying to save this python file with django, but it appears that python doesn't recognize these attributes.

Oh, and yeah, I installed django correctly. No issues.

Comment: What are you trying to do? According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/), `File` only has a `save` method if it is associated with an object.

Comment: I'm trying to connect Django to Python through an ORM. Maybe my title is incorrect.

Comment: Not just the title. Your `myfile` isn't associated to an object, so it doesn't have a `save` method. But I don't think anyone can help you without knowing your ultimate goal.

Comment: Paulo has explained why you are getting the error. `File` objects are typically used within model fields like FileField. Perhaps start with the [Django docs on uploading a file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Answer (score 0):

the Django File class doesn't have a method "save"  Here are the Django Docs for the File class:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/